# Exclude column from export in Datatables Tabletools

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables, tabletools

I have the following initialization for my datatables:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datatable').dataTable({
        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "tableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "/js/plugins/dataTables/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
        },
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": 'no-sort',
            "orderable": false
        }]

    });
});
```

The TableTools plugin for DT gives me the flash buttons for export. I would like to exclude table columns of a certain class `.no-export`. I am aware of the `mColumns` option but I cannot get it to apply for a column by class. I have read the answer here [Excluding last column of jQuery DataTables.net TableTools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780851/excluding-last-column-of-jquery-datatables-net-tabletools) where Joe Jonston suggest the possibility by setting:

```
"aoColumnDefs": [{ "mColumns": false, "aTargets": ["no-export"] }],
```

I have tried applying the code in various ways but there is something missing in my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26970551/3549014) for a possible solution.

You can use `mColumns` to define a function that will return indexes of all columns having class `no-export` assigned to `th` element in the header.

```
$('.datatable').dataTable({
    "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    "tableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "/js/plugins/dataTables/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
        "aButtons": [{
          "sExtends": "csv",
          "mColumns": function (settings) {
               var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api( settings );
               return api.columns(":not(.no-export)").indexes().toArray();
          }
        }]
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm just trying this, but it seems like the code actually exports the opposite, the columns with class `.no-export` - however almost there...

Comment: @jtheman, you're right, it does the opposite, I have corrected the code.

Comment: Fantastic! :) Thanks!